# hybrid property with join in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have probably not grasped the use of `@hybrid_property` fully. But what I try to do is to make it easy to access a calculated value based on a column in another table and thus a join is required.

So what I have is something like this (which works but is awkward and feels wrong):

```
class Item():

:

@hybrid_property
def days_ago(self):
    # Can I even write a python version of this ?
    pass

@days_ago.expression
def days_ago(cls):
    return func.datediff(func.NOW(), func.MAX(Event.date_started))
```

This requires me to add the join on the `Action` table by the caller when I need to use the days_ago property. Is the hybrid_property even the correct approach to simplifying my queries where I need to get hold of the days_ago value ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way or another you need to load or access `Action` rows either via join or via lazy load (note here it's not clear what `Event` vs. `Action` is, I'm assuming you have just `Item.actions -> Action`).

The non-"expression" version of `days_ago` intends to function against `Action` objects that are relevant only to the current instance.   Normally within a hybrid, this means just iterating through `Item.actions` and performing the operation in Python against loaded `Action` objects.  Though in this case you're looking for a simple aggregate you could instead opt to run a query, but again it would be local to `self` so this is like `object_session(self).query(func.datediff(...)).select_from(Action).with_parent(self).scalar()`.

The expression version of the hybrid when formed against another table typically requires that the query in which it is used already have the correct FROM clauses set up, so it would look like `session.query(Item).join(Item.actions).filter(Item.days_ago == xyz)`.  This is explained at [Join-Dependent Relationship Hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#join-dependent-relationship-hybrid).

your expression here might be better produced as a column_property, if you can afford using a correlated subquery.  See that at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html#using-column-property-for-column-level-options.